Downloading Python 2.x.x gives a 403
I'm trying to use node-gyp to build VSCode from source. And node-gyp requires windows-build-tools from npm:
npm i --global --production windows-build-tools

But I get:
npm error path C:\Users\leroy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./dist/index.js
npm error Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
npm error [>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
npm error ^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0KDownloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi      
npm error Error: GET https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi returned 403  
npm error Downloading Python failed. Error: Error: GET https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi returned 403

If I go to the Python download website, I see the same 403 error.


I'm trying to use node-gyp to build VSCode from source.

I've put this here because I am open to workarounds to build VSCode without all this extra setup. I don't need a executable. Just want to be able to run a Code - OSS window on my machine.
EDIT: I have no VPN.

i just checked node-gyp page because python2 is obsolete, and they say Install tools with Chocolatey

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi seems to be valid for me.

It is now working... Sorry.
